# Java and unicode

Tags: java, netbeans, unicode, jar

I'm a newbie in java and I'm having problems with non-ascii characters. In netbeans I made GUI for my java app. When i run that app from netbeans, everything is working fine, but when I run standalone .jar file, non-ascii chars are not shown correctly.

Thanks for any possible solutions or guidance.

Comment: Where is the text coming from? Java uses Unicode characters so literals within the Java code should be ok.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are running command line application. In this case, you may be running it in terminal window that can't show unicode properly. In NetBeans it works because console output is shown in the IDE window that knows how to display it correctly.

If I am correct in my assumption, you will need to configure your terminal properly and that depends on the operating system and UI manager.